# Multi-module Spring Boot Application shutdowns immediately

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I'm trying to migrate a monolythic spring app to a multi-module one. Here is the few important files

```
--api/
---src/
---pom.xml [api]
--core/
---src/
---pom.xml [core]
--web/
---src/
---pom.xml [web]
--pom.xml [main]
```

### pom.xml [main]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>main</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>web</module>
        <module>core</module>
        <module>api</module>
    </modules>

</project>
```

### pom.xml [web]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>web</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent getFormatFromXDocKind repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
              <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
              </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

### web\src\main\java\com\example\MyApp.java

```
package com.example;

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.example"})
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class MyApp {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(MyApp.class, args);
  }


}
```

I have my `RestController` next to the file, and main services in `core`. However when I try to run my App:

```
DEBUG StatusLogger Using ShutdownCallbackRegistry class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.DefaultShutdownCallbackRegistry
INFO StatusLogger Log4j appears to be running in a Servlet environment, but there's no log4j-web module available. If you want better web container support, please add the log4j-web JAR to your web archive or server lib directory.
INFO StatusLogger Log4j appears to be running in a Servlet environment, but there's no log4j-web module available. If you want better web container support, please add the log4j-web JAR to your web archive or server lib directory.
DEBUG StatusLogger Took 0,074115 seconds to load 207 plugins from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2
DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'Converter' found 45 plugins
DEBUG StatusLogger Starting OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false.false-1
DEBUG StatusLogger Starting LoggerContext[name=18b4aac2, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@2f943d71]...
DEBUG StatusLogger Reconfiguration started for context[name=18b4aac2] at URI null (org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@2f943d71) with optional ClassLoader: null
INFO StatusLogger Log4j appears to be running in a Servlet environment, but there's no log4j-web module available. If you want better web container support, please add the log4j-web JAR to your web archive or server lib directory.
DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'ConfigurationFactory' found 5 plugins
INFO StatusLogger Log4j appears to be running in a Servlet environment, but there's no log4j-web module available. If you want better web container support, please add the log4j-web JAR to your web archive or server lib directory.
INFO StatusLogger Log4j appears to be running in a Servlet environment, but there's no log4j-web module available. If you want better web container support, please add the log4j-web JAR to your web archive or server lib directory.
DEBUG StatusLogger Missing dependencies for Yaml support, ConfigurationFactory org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.yaml.YamlConfigurationFactory is inactive
INFO StatusLogger Log4j appears to be running in a Servlet environment, but there's no log4j-web module available. If you want better web container support, please add the log4j-web JAR to your web archive or server lib directory.
INFO StatusLogger Log4j appears to be running in a Servlet environment, but there's no log4j-web module available. If you want better web container support, please add the log4j-web JAR to your web archive or server lib directory.
INFO StatusLogger Log4j appears to be running in a Servlet environment, but there's no log4j-web module available. If you want better web container support, please add the log4j-web JAR to your web archive or server lib directory.
DEBUG StatusLogger Using configurationFactory org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory$Factory@6b57696f
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test18b4aac2.properties] using context class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2
...
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2.xml] using context class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2.
INFO StatusLogger Log4j appears to be running in a Servlet environment, but there's no log4j-web module available. If you want better web container support, please add the log4j-web JAR to your web archive or server lib directory.
DEBUG StatusLogger Initializing configuration XmlConfiguration[location=C:\Users\Me\IdeaProjects\example\web\target\classes\log4j2.xml]
DEBUG StatusLogger Installed 1 script engine
DEBUG StatusLogger Oracle Nashorn version: 1.8.0_181, language: ECMAScript, threading: Not Thread Safe, compile: true, names: [nashorn, Nashorn, js, JS, JavaScript, javascript, ECMAScript, ecmascript], factory class: jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngineFactory
DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'Core' found 116 plugins
DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'Level' found 0 plugins
DEBUG StatusLogger Building Plugin[name=property, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Property].
TRACE StatusLogger TypeConverterRegistry initializing.
DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'TypeConverter' found 26 plugins
DEBUG StatusLogger createProperty(name="LOG_PATTERN", value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %5p VRS --- [%15.15t] %-40.40c{1.} : %m%n%ex")
DEBUG StatusLogger Building Plugin[name=properties, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.PropertiesPlugin].
DEBUG StatusLogger configureSubstitutor(={LOG_PATTERN=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %5p VRS --- [%15.15t] %-40.40c{1.} : %m%n%ex}, Configuration(C:\Users\Me\IdeaProjects\example\web\target\classes\log4j2.xml))
DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'Lookup' found 13 plugins
DEBUG StatusLogger Building Plugin[name=layout, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout].
DEBUG StatusLogger PatternLayout$Builder(pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %5p VRS --- [%15.15t] %-40.40c{1.} : %m%n%ex", PatternSelector=null, Configuration(C:\Users\Me\IdeaProjects\example\web\target\classes\log4j2.xml), Replace=null, charset="null", alwaysWriteExceptions="null", disableAnsi="null", noConsoleNoAnsi="null", header="null", footer="null")
DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'Converter' found 45 plugins
DEBUG StatusLogger Building Plugin[name=appender, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.ConsoleAppender].
DEBUG StatusLogger ConsoleAppender$Builder(target="SYSTEM_OUT", follow="true", direct="null", bufferedIo="null", bufferSize="null", immediateFlush="null", ignoreExceptions="null", PatternLayout(%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %5p VRS --- [%15.15t] %-40.40c{1.} : %m%n%ex), name="ConsoleAppender", Configuration(C:\Users\Me\IdeaProjects\example\web\target\classes\log4j2.xml), Filter=null)
DEBUG StatusLogger Starting OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.true.false
DEBUG StatusLogger Building Plugin[name=appenders, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppendersPlugin].
DEBUG StatusLogger createAppenders(={ConsoleAppender})
DEBUG StatusLogger Building Plugin[name=AppenderRef, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef].
DEBUG StatusLogger createAppenderRef(ref="ConsoleAppender", level="null", Filter=null)
DEBUG StatusLogger Building Plugin[name=root, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig$RootLogger].
DEBUG StatusLogger createLogger(additivity="null", level="INFO", includeLocation="null", ={ConsoleAppender}, ={}, Configuration(C:\Users\Me\IdeaProjects\example\web\target\classes\log4j2.xml), Filter=null)
DEBUG StatusLogger Building Plugin[name=AppenderRef, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef].
DEBUG StatusLogger createAppenderRef(ref="ConsoleAppender", level="null", Filter=null)
DEBUG StatusLogger Building Plugin[name=logger, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig].
DEBUG StatusLogger createLogger(additivity="false", level="DEBUG", name="com.example", includeLocation="null", ={ConsoleAppender}, ={}, Configuration(C:\Users\Me\IdeaProjects\example\web\target\classes\log4j2.xml), Filter=null)
DEBUG StatusLogger Building Plugin[name=AppenderRef, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef].
DEBUG StatusLogger createAppenderRef(ref="ConsoleAppender", level="null", Filter=null)
DEBUG StatusLogger Building Plugin[name=logger, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig].
DEBUG StatusLogger createLogger(additivity="false", level="DEBUG", name="fr.opensagres.xdocreport.core.logging.LogUtils", includeLocation="null", ={ConsoleAppender}, ={}, Configuration(C:\Users\Me\IdeaProjects\example\web\target\classes\log4j2.xml), Filter=null)
DEBUG StatusLogger Building Plugin[name=loggers, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggersPlugin].
DEBUG StatusLogger createLoggers(={root, com.example, fr.opensagres.xdocreport.core.logging.LogUtils})
DEBUG StatusLogger Configuration XmlConfiguration[location=C:\Users\Me\IdeaProjects\example\web\target\classes\log4j2.xml] initialized
DEBUG StatusLogger Starting configuration XmlConfiguration[location=C:\Users\Me\IdeaProjects\example\web\target\classes\log4j2.xml]
DEBUG StatusLogger Started configuration XmlConfiguration[location=C:\Users\Me\IdeaProjects\example\web\target\classes\log4j2.xml] OK.
TRACE StatusLogger Stopping org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.DefaultConfiguration@e580929...
TRACE StatusLogger DefaultConfiguration notified 1 ReliabilityStrategies that config will be stopped.
TRACE StatusLogger DefaultConfiguration stopping root LoggerConfig.
TRACE StatusLogger DefaultConfiguration notifying ReliabilityStrategies that appenders will be stopped.
TRACE StatusLogger DefaultConfiguration stopping remaining Appenders.
DEBUG StatusLogger Shutting down OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false.false-1
DEBUG StatusLogger Shut down OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false.false-1, all resources released: true
DEBUG StatusLogger Appender DefaultConsole-1 stopped with status true
TRACE StatusLogger DefaultConfiguration stopped 1 remaining Appenders.
TRACE StatusLogger DefaultConfiguration cleaning Appenders from 1 LoggerConfigs.
DEBUG StatusLogger Stopped org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.DefaultConfiguration@e580929 OK
TRACE StatusLogger Reregistering MBeans after reconfigure. Selector=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector@394a2528
TRACE StatusLogger Reregistering context (1/1): '18b4aac2' org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@2f943d71
TRACE StatusLogger Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2'
TRACE StatusLogger Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2,component=StatusLogger'
TRACE StatusLogger Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2,component=ContextSelector'
TRACE StatusLogger Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2,component=Loggers,name=*'
TRACE StatusLogger Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2,component=Appenders,name=*'
TRACE StatusLogger Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2,component=AsyncAppenders,name=*'
TRACE StatusLogger Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2,component=AsyncLoggerRingBuffer'
TRACE StatusLogger Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2,component=Loggers,name=*,subtype=RingBuffer'
DEBUG StatusLogger Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2
DEBUG StatusLogger Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2,component=StatusLogger
DEBUG StatusLogger Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2,component=ContextSelector
DEBUG StatusLogger Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2,component=Loggers,name=
DEBUG StatusLogger Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2,component=Loggers,name=fr.opensagres.xdocreport.core.logging.LogUtils
DEBUG StatusLogger Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2,component=Loggers,name=com.example
DEBUG StatusLogger Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2,component=Appenders,name=ConsoleAppender
TRACE StatusLogger Using default SystemClock for timestamps.
TRACE StatusLogger Using DummyNanoClock for nanosecond timestamps.
DEBUG StatusLogger Reconfiguration complete for context[name=18b4aac2] at URI C:\Users\Me\IdeaProjects\example\web\target\classes\log4j2.xml (org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@2f943d71) with optional ClassLoader: null
DEBUG StatusLogger Shutdown hook enabled. Registering a new one.
DEBUG StatusLogger LoggerContext[name=18b4aac2, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@2f943d71] started OK.
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
DEBUG StatusLogger Reconfiguration started for context[name=18b4aac2] at URI null (org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@2f943d71) with optional ClassLoader: null
DEBUG StatusLogger Using configurationFactory org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory$Factory@6b57696f
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test18b4aac2.properties] using context class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2
...
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2.xml] using context class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2.
INFO StatusLogger Log4j appears to be running in a Servlet environment, but there's no log4j-web module available. If you want better web container support, please add the log4j-web JAR to your web archive or server lib directory.
DEBUG StatusLogger Initializing configuration XmlConfiguration[location=C:\Users\Me\IdeaProjects\example\web\target\classes\log4j2.xml]
DEBUG StatusLogger Installed 1 script engine
DEBUG StatusLogger Oracle Nashorn version: 1.8.0_181, language: ECMAScript, threading: Not Thread Safe, compile: true, names: [nashorn, Nashorn, js, JS, JavaScript, javascript, ECMAScript, ecmascript], factory class: jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngineFactory
DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'Core' found 116 plugins
DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'Level' found 0 plugins
DEBUG StatusLogger Building Plugin[name=property, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Property].
DEBUG StatusLogger createProperty(name="LOG_PATTERN", value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %5p VRS --- [%15.15t] %-40.40c{1.} : %m%n%ex")
DEBUG StatusLogger Building Plugin[name=properties, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.PropertiesPlugin].
DEBUG StatusLogger configureSubstitutor(={LOG_PATTERN=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %5p VRS --- [%15.15t] %-40.40c{1.} : %m%n%ex}, Configuration(C:\Users\Me\IdeaProjects\example\web\target\classes\log4j2.xml))
DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'Lookup' found 13 plugins
DEBUG StatusLogger Building Plugin[name=layout, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout].
DEBUG StatusLogger PatternLayout$Builder(pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %5p VRS --- [%15.15t] %-40.40c{1.} : %m%n%ex", PatternSelector=null, Configuration(C:\Users\Me\IdeaProjects\example\web\target\classes\log4j2.xml), Replace=null, charset="null", alwaysWriteExceptions="null", disableAnsi="null", noConsoleNoAnsi="null", header="null", footer="null")
DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'Converter' found 45 plugins
DEBUG StatusLogger Building Plugin[name=appender, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.ConsoleAppender].
DEBUG StatusLogger ConsoleAppender$Builder(target="SYSTEM_OUT", follow="true", direct="null", bufferedIo="null", bufferSize="null", immediateFlush="null", ignoreExceptions="null", PatternLayout(%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %5p VRS --- [%15.15t] %-40.40c{1.} : %m%n%ex), name="ConsoleAppender", Configuration(C:\Users\Me\IdeaProjects\example\web\target\classes\log4j2.xml), Filter=null)
DEBUG StatusLogger Building Plugin[name=appenders, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppendersPlugin].
DEBUG StatusLogger createAppenders(={ConsoleAppender})
DEBUG StatusLogger Building Plugin[name=AppenderRef, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef].
DEBUG StatusLogger createAppenderRef(ref="ConsoleAppender", level="null", Filter=null)
DEBUG StatusLogger Building Plugin[name=root, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig$RootLogger].
DEBUG StatusLogger createLogger(additivity="null", level="INFO", includeLocation="null", ={ConsoleAppender}, ={}, Configuration(C:\Users\Me\IdeaProjects\example\web\target\classes\log4j2.xml), Filter=null)
DEBUG StatusLogger Building Plugin[name=AppenderRef, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef].
DEBUG StatusLogger createAppenderRef(ref="ConsoleAppender", level="null", Filter=null)
DEBUG StatusLogger Building Plugin[name=logger, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig].
DEBUG StatusLogger createLogger(additivity="false", level="DEBUG", name="com.example", includeLocation="null", ={ConsoleAppender}, ={}, Configuration(C:\Users\Me\IdeaProjects\example\web\target\classes\log4j2.xml), Filter=null)
DEBUG StatusLogger Building Plugin[name=AppenderRef, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef].
DEBUG StatusLogger createAppenderRef(ref="ConsoleAppender", level="null", Filter=null)
DEBUG StatusLogger Building Plugin[name=logger, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig].
DEBUG StatusLogger createLogger(additivity="false", level="DEBUG", name="fr.opensagres.xdocreport.core.logging.LogUtils", includeLocation="null", ={ConsoleAppender}, ={}, Configuration(C:\Users\Me\IdeaProjects\example\web\target\classes\log4j2.xml), Filter=null)
DEBUG StatusLogger Building Plugin[name=loggers, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggersPlugin].
DEBUG StatusLogger createLoggers(={root, com.example, fr.opensagres.xdocreport.core.logging.LogUtils})
DEBUG StatusLogger Configuration XmlConfiguration[location=C:\Users\Me\IdeaProjects\example\web\target\classes\log4j2.xml] initialized
DEBUG StatusLogger Starting configuration XmlConfiguration[location=C:\Users\Me\IdeaProjects\example\web\target\classes\log4j2.xml]
DEBUG StatusLogger Started configuration XmlConfiguration[location=C:\Users\Me\IdeaProjects\example\web\target\classes\log4j2.xml] OK.
TRACE StatusLogger Stopping XmlConfiguration[location=C:\Users\Me\IdeaProjects\example\web\target\classes\log4j2.xml]...
TRACE StatusLogger XmlConfiguration notified 4 ReliabilityStrategies that config will be stopped.
TRACE StatusLogger XmlConfiguration stopping 3 LoggerConfigs.
TRACE StatusLogger XmlConfiguration stopping root LoggerConfig.
TRACE StatusLogger XmlConfiguration notifying ReliabilityStrategies that appenders will be stopped.
TRACE StatusLogger XmlConfiguration stopping remaining Appenders.
DEBUG StatusLogger Appender ConsoleAppender stopped with status true
TRACE StatusLogger XmlConfiguration stopped 1 remaining Appenders.
TRACE StatusLogger XmlConfiguration cleaning Appenders from 4 LoggerConfigs.
DEBUG StatusLogger Stopped XmlConfiguration[location=C:\Users\Me\IdeaProjects\example\web\target\classes\log4j2.xml] OK
TRACE StatusLogger Reregistering MBeans after reconfigure. Selector=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector@394a2528
TRACE StatusLogger Reregistering context (1/1): '18b4aac2' org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@2f943d71
TRACE StatusLogger Unregistering 1 MBeans: [org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2]
TRACE StatusLogger Unregistering 1 MBeans: [org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2,component=StatusLogger]
TRACE StatusLogger Unregistering 1 MBeans: [org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2,component=ContextSelector]
TRACE StatusLogger Unregistering 3 MBeans: [org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2,component=Loggers,name=fr.opensagres.xdocreport.core.logging.LogUtils, org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2,component=Loggers,name=, org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2,component=Loggers,name=com.example]
TRACE StatusLogger Unregistering 1 MBeans: [org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2,component=Appenders,name=ConsoleAppender]
TRACE StatusLogger Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2,component=AsyncAppenders,name=*'
TRACE StatusLogger Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2,component=AsyncLoggerRingBuffer'
TRACE StatusLogger Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2,component=Loggers,name=*,subtype=RingBuffer'
DEBUG StatusLogger Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2
DEBUG StatusLogger Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2,component=StatusLogger
DEBUG StatusLogger Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2,component=ContextSelector
DEBUG StatusLogger Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2,component=Loggers,name=
DEBUG StatusLogger Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2,component=Loggers,name=fr.opensagres.xdocreport.core.logging.LogUtils
DEBUG StatusLogger Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2,component=Loggers,name=com.example
DEBUG StatusLogger Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2,component=Appenders,name=ConsoleAppender
TRACE StatusLogger Using DummyNanoClock for nanosecond timestamps.
DEBUG StatusLogger Reconfiguration complete for context[name=18b4aac2] at URI C:\Users\Me\IdeaProjects\example\web\target\classes\log4j2.xml (org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@2f943d71) with optional ClassLoader: null

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.5.RELEASE)

DEBUG StatusLogger AsyncLogger.ThreadNameStrategy=UNCACHED (user specified null, default is UNCACHED)
2018-10-24 12:05:53.563  INFO VRS --- [           main] o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol                : Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
TRACE StatusLogger Using default SystemClock for timestamps.
2018-10-24 12:05:53.573  INFO VRS --- [           main] o.a.c.c.StandardService                  : Starting service [Tomcat]
2018-10-24 12:05:53.573  INFO VRS --- [           main] o.a.c.c.StandardEngine                   : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.34
2018-10-24 12:05:53.576  INFO VRS --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.AprLifecycleListener             : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin;C:\windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;.]
2018-10-24 12:05:53.629  INFO VRS --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/]                        : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2018-10-24 12:05:53.708  INFO VRS --- [           main] o.a.c.c.StandardService                  : Stopping service [Tomcat]

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: I see your project depends on itself `<dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>web</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>`

Comment: indeed, my mistake, fixed it